# how to see a difference between entity and a column

Tags: database

Sometimes I am having a hard time seeing a difference between an entity and a column when I am starting to make a diagram. I don't know when it is supposed to be a entity or a column. For example, in some game if you have a user and that user can play by itself or it can play in the group. Would you make that two different entities `User` and `GroupUser` ?

Also, for example if the `User` has levels, status and badges they earn which is part of the game. Would these be entities also or they would just be in one entity which would be part of the User ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Entity` could be a `Person` (e.g. Student), `Place` (e.g. Room Name), `Object` (e.g. Books), `Abstract Concept` (e.g. Course, Order) that could be represented in your database and normally could become a `Table` in your `Database`.

`Column(s)` on the other hand is/are the **attribute(s)** of your `Entity`.

So, in your case you have a User entity and the possible columns or attributes (or fields) are
`UserID`, `UserLevel`, `UserStatus`, `Badges`, `PlayStatus` (values could be individual or group).

Your `Badges` although is a column could turn into `Entity` if it violates the [`Normalization` rules](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/dbms/database_normalization.htm).

For example if you have this Table for User:

```
 Table: Users

 UserID    UserName    UserStatus   PlayStatus   Badges
 ------    --------    ----------   ----------   ------
  1        Surefire    Active       Single       Private, Warrior, Platoon Leader
  2        FastMachine Active       Group        Private, Warrior
  3        BeatTheGeek Inactive     Group        Private
```

The Badges here violates the `1NF (1st Normal Form)` in `Normalization` rules which says that there should be no repeating groups or in this case no Multi-valued columns. So, this could be normalized like:

```
 Table: Users

 UserID    UserName    UserStatus   PlayStatus   
 ------    --------    ----------   ---------- 
  1        Surefire    Active       Single       
  2        FastMachine Active       Group        
  3        BeatTheGeek Inactive     Group        

 Table: Badges

 BadgeID   BadgeName   
 ------    --------  
  1        Private            
  2        Indie
  3        Warrior
  4        Platoon Leader
  5        Colonel
  6        1 Star General
  7        2 Star General
  8        3 Star General
  9        4 Star General
  10       5 Star General
  11       Hero

 Table: UserBadgesHistory

 UserID    BadgeID    ReceiveDate
 ------    --------   -----------
  1         1         12/01/2013
  1         3         12/05/2013
  1         4         1/5/2014
  2         1         2/5/2014
  2         3         2/10/2014
  3         2         11/10/2013
```

Comment: so if you were just starting to do the diagram for a conceptual design..you would still have badges a separate entity ?...you made badges seperate entity because there is more than one type of badge ?

Comment: Yes, in a diagram for a conceptual design the Badges is a separate entity because the cardinality is one-to-many, that is, a User could have one or many badges (if it is mandatory) or zero or many badges (if it is optional).

Comment: you made my night..finally I understand what I asked!...glad you mentioned repeating groups here..thank you

Comment: Glad to be of help @Ris. Happy coding, good night and GOD bless you in your quest to learn Database Design ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In general, an entity has multiple columns (i.e. attributes) of its own, and a column (or attribute) does not.

In your example, if the only data you're interested in storing is a User's current level, then level is unlikely to be an entity. This is because it would have only a single attribute of name/number. If you wanted to find all Users currently at level 4, you would simply do a query with `level = 4`.

On the other hand, if you had a reason to add additional data about the level, such as what abilities are associated with that level or the date a given User achieved the level, then you would want to make Level a separate entity.

A Level entity would have an ID, a number or name, and whatever other attributes you need as data.

```
 ID | Prerequisite |   Ability
----+--------------+--------------
 1  | NULL         | May gain foos
 2  | Gain 10 foos | May gain bars
 3  | Gain 20 bars | 30 free foos
```

In a fully normalized state, you would have another entity called UserLevel in which you would store data about, for example, when a certain User gained a level.

The UserLevel entity would contain the LevelID and the UserID as foreign keys (links back to the other entities), and a DateAchieved column for when the User achieved the level.

```
 LevelID | UserID | DateAchieved
---------+--------+-------------
 1       | 1      | 2014-02-01
 1       | 2      | 2014-02-01
 2       | 1      | 2014-02-05
 3       | 1      | 2014-02-09
 2       | 2      | 2014-02-11
 4       | 1      | 2014-02-13
```

This shows User 1 and User 2 starting at Level 1 on the same day and leveling up at different rates.

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for. In most cases you would have more than 1 level and have additional data where you want to keep track of the tasks. Like boolean task1, task2 task3 etc. So yeah that would def be an entity.